# Visual studio project compiles but solution doesn't (because of project)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, solution, vcproj

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2008 with multiple projects. I'm using boost in one of them. I've included all the necessary directories and path etc. When I compile the project with that's using boost, it compiles perfectly. When I build the entire solution, it fails and tells me that it can't find a header of boost that I'm using. But it's in the project that compiles. How is this possible?

I've cleaned, rebuilt (the solution and the project) and open and reopened visual studio. Still nothing...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it.

Apparently there was another project that referenced this project and used a header file from it (which included some boost files). Apparently I had to add the boost library dependencies in the second project as well. (Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General --> Additional include libraries AND Configuration properties -> Linker --> Additional Library Directories)